# Conda and Anaconda running different Python Installs?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Using conda to update conda, and then anaconda, seems to be working on two different installs of python.  And therefore seem to work against one another.  For example:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ conda update conda
Error: unknown host: http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/

Package plan for installation in environment /Users/myname/anaconda:

The following packages will be UN-linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.5               |                3
    readline-6.2               |                1

The following packages will be linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.6               |                1   hard-link
    readline-6.2               |                2   hard-link

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |##################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |##################################################| 100%
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ conda update anaconda

Package plan for installation in environment /Users/myname/anaconda:

The following packages will be UN-linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.6               |                1
    readline-6.2               |                2

The following packages will be linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.5               |                3   hard-link
    readline-6.2               |                1   hard-link

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |##################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |##################################################| 100%
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ conda update conda

Package plan for installation in environment /Users/myname/anaconda:

The following packages will be UN-linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.5               |                3
    readline-6.2               |                1

The following packages will be linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.6               |                1   hard-link
    readline-6.2               |                2   hard-link

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Recommendations for how to deal with this, it's not a huge issue at the moment functionality wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the version of Python in the latest version of Anaconda is 2.7.5. When a new version of Anaconda is released (which should happen this week), this problem will go away.

The `anaconda` package is a stable set of versions packages of packages that have been tested against one another. Hence, installing or updating anaconda may downgrade Python, because that is the version that is in Anaconda.